# How To Poll multiple emails in Spring-Integration mail support

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement to poll a mail server. As  my project already in Spring i used  Spring-Integration to poll the mail server. I was successful in that. But now i have to poll multiple emails. can some body let me know how to do it.

This is the sample code i used to poll a single mail.

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                      store-uri="${imap.uri}"                                    
                                      channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                         
                                      should-delete-messages="false"
                                      should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                     
                                      auto-startup="true"
                                      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${imap.poolerSecondsDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
    </mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">        
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>

    <bean id="emailReceiverService" class="com.usbank.hermes.serviceimpl.EmailReceiverService">
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the "max-messages-per-poll" to your poller.

ie:

```
<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-delay="${imap.poolerSecondsDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
```

which should fetch 10 mails from the queue each poll.